# Stone falls from a balloon thats descending @ 12 m/s. What will be the displacement of the stone from the point of release after 10 seconds?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, free-fall

Question based on Motion in a Straight Line:

> “A stone falls from a balloon that is descending at a uniform rate of 12 m per second. What will be the displacement of the stone from the point of release after 10 seconds?”

I solved this question assuming that the balloon is also descending at a rate of 12 metres per second. So when the stone falls, it also has the initial velocity of 12 metres per second.

Using the second equation of motion, I found the distance travelled by the stone to be equal to 610 m. Applying the similar logic, balloon has also descended by 120 m by now.

Show the resultant displacement should have been 490 given that the stone has fallen off the surface of balloon as per what the question should be asking.

Yet, in the answer key, it has been mentioned that the answer is 610 m only. How does this happen given that the balloon should also have descended from its initial position?

Answer (score 1):

The key is the phrase "Point of release". The point of release is the point in space from where the stone was released. You are incorrectly trying to measure the relative displacement between the balloon and the stone, which is not asked here. You need to measure the absolute displacement of the stone, which turns out to be $610 \ \text{m}$.